# Can $\Pr(t<\infty)=1$ follow from $\Pr(t<N)>1-\delta$?

Tags: probability, limits

If we know that $\forall \delta>0, \exists N \in \mathbb{N} $, s.t.
$
\Pr(t<N)>1-\delta
$, does it follow that $\Pr(t<\infty)=1$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, $P(t=\infty) \leq P(t \geq N)=1-P(t<N) <1-(1-\delta)=\delta$. Since $\delta$ is arbitrary we get $P(t=\infty)=0$.

Comment: I need a little help here. Why is $P(t=\infty) \le P(t \ge N)$?

Comment: $P(A) \leq P(B)$ if $A \subset B$. Here $(t\infty) \subset (t \geq N)$